# How to use gulp-uncss-task for remote files

Tags: node.js, gulp

**Preface**:
I'm using [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) and, as the instructions say, using it from a command line is straight forward:

```
uncss [options] <file or url, ...>
e.g. uncss http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/ > stylesheet.css
```

And, as stated this works with remote files (even php scripts), so that I can for example call:

```
uncss http://www.example.com/myPage.php > myPage.css
```

and it would work flawlessly.

Also, I got it working in Node.js app (as per instructions from the documentation):

```
var uncss = require('uncss');

var files   = [],
    options = {
        urls         : ['http://www.example.com/myPage.php'], // Deprecated
    };

uncss(files, options, function (error, output) {
    console.log(output);
});
```

I'm wondering why the `Deprecated` comment up in the `urls` - I couldn't find any additional info for this?

**Actual question**: Since I use gulp to run my build tasks I would like to use [gulp-unss-task](https://github.com/addyosmani/gulp-uncss-task) to achieve the same thing (uncssing the remote file) so that I could then pipe it further to the minimization task. As it seems from the documentation this is not possible, but would appreciate if someone dealt with this before and maybe has a solution.

The usage docs for gulp-uncss-task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uncss = require('gulp-uncss-task');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('bootstrap.css')
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: ['index.html', 'contact.html', 'about.html']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://uncss.io/ , maybe they can help you, since I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintain [gulp-uncss](https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-uncss). What you will want to do is pass through your URLs using the `html` option; `urls` is deprecated because of this feature. I realise that this isn't documented properly in the readme for the plugin so I'm going to go update that. But in the meantime this code will help:

```
gulp.task('uncss', function() {
    gulp.src('site.css')
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: [
                'http://www.example.com/myPage.php'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./out'));
});
```

Note that you must pass an array here if you want to specify file paths/URLs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Yes, please do update the docs. Great work btw!